# ios regex remove inline javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, regex

I'm parsing a xhtml document but I want to remove all tags, just to keep the plain text.
This is what I do :

```
NSRange r;
NSString *s = from;

while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
}
```

It works for example on :

```
<h1>Hello</h1> which renders Hello
<a href="hello.html'>Hello</a> which also renders Hello
```

Perfect.

But I also want to remove the content of inline script tags

```
<script ...> here is some Js I want to remove </script>
```

And of course, with the initial regex, script and /script are removed, but the JS inside is not.

So I need to write an other Regex such as

```
@"/<script((?:(?!src=).)*?)>(.*?)</script>/smix"
```

which does not work

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I could parse the DOM looking for scripts node with the TFHpple library.
Then I removed this node and that's it !